# What's the purpose of this flood of nonsense answers?

Tags: discussion

Tonight, there's a torrent of *Lorem ipsum* answers this evening.  What's the goal?

Comment: There was also a flood the previous day.

Answer (score 7):

It's just someone trying to disrupt the site. Please keep flagging anything you see and we'll deal with it asap.

Comment: Sure it's not somebody trying to get past the spam filters by generating enough account activity to look legit? (I didn't see any of the posts.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm sure :-) We know what was going on, it's just not appropriate to go into the details in public.

Comment: OK -- that's entirely appropriate. :-)